# how to access elements of object type from a hash map

Tags: java, oop

I am newbie in Java and I have a hash map with

`Map<Integer, x> dataset = new HashMap<Integer, x>();`

X has

```
 public int id; 
 public Integer getID(){
        return id;
    }
```

and its constructor.

I insert values to X and the HashMap. But how do I

Access the elements of X ? 
`myMap.myX.getID()` ? This is what I have tried and it fails.

Best way to iterate through the list?

Comment: That is not how you use a Map! Read the documentation and learn Java syntax better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) iterface exposes a `get` method to retrieve elements:

```
X mapObject = dataset.get(someInteger);
```

or a more concrete example:

```
dataset.put(5, new X());
X mapObject = dataset.get(5);
```

And to iterate you can do:

```
for (X mapObject:dataset.values())
```

to iterate over the values or

```
for (Integer mapKey:dataet.keySet())
```

to iterate over the keys

Answer (score 0):

you must use Map's `get()` method to access object.

`dataset.get(key).getID()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your `Object` from the `map` based on a `key` and then try to access its elements.

```
for(Integer key : dataset.keySet()){
    X object = dataset.get(key);
    // Access its elements like "object.getID()";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Map<Integer, X> map = new HashMap<Integer,X>();
Iterator<Integer> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();

while ( iterator.hasNext() ) {
    Integer key = iterator.next();
    X x = map.get(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you get all the ids......

```
for(Integer key : dataset.keySet()){
    X object = dataset.get(key);
    int objectId = object.getId();
}
```